# Inserting rows in a specific place in dataframe in R

Tags: r, insert, row

The dataset (named Politics) that I am working on looks as follows:

[Current Dataset of every country in the world](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkBkB.png)

However, my original data set contains the years 1997, 1999 and 2001 as well.
As one can see in the picture, every country has no data for 1997, 1999 and 2001.

I would like to insert rows of the year 1997, 1999 and 2001 for every country in the current dataset such that we would have something like:

```
Country     Year    Politics
Afghanistan 1996    Value 1
Afghanistan 1997    empty value
Afghanistan 1998    Value 2
....
....
....
Albania     1996    Value 3
Albania     1997    empty value
etc
etc
```

Is there maybe another way because my original dataset looks as follows:
[Original dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5kfF.png)

The conclusion is that I want to make the current dataset fitted to the original dataset and currrently this is not possible as the original dataset has the years 1997, 1999 and 2001 whereas the current dataset did not include these years.

I hope that I have given a clear explanation of what I would like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `complete` from `tidyr`. You can specify explicitly the years you want for each country, or refer to your second data.frame's years. Below includes example data based on your post (recommend using `dput` to share data instead of image).

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  Country = c(rep("Afghanistan", 4), rep("Albania", 4)),
  Time = c(1996, 1998, 2000, 2002, 1996, 1998, 2000, 2002),
  Politics = rnorm(n = 8)
)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  complete(Time = 1996:2002, nesting(Country)) %>%
  arrange(Country, Time)
```

**Output**

```
    Time Country     Politics
   <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
 1  1996 Afghanistan  -0.230 
 2  1997 Afghanistan  NA     
 3  1998 Afghanistan   1.56  
 4  1999 Afghanistan  NA     
 5  2000 Afghanistan   0.0705
 6  2001 Afghanistan  NA     
 7  2002 Afghanistan   0.129 
 8  1996 Albania       1.72  
 9  1997 Albania      NA     
10  1998 Albania       0.461 
11  1999 Albania      NA     
12  2000 Albania      -1.27  
13  2001 Albania      NA     
14  2002 Albania      -0.687
```

Comment: However, I need to do this for 200 countries. Therefore, it would be a very large code. Is there another possibility where I could just insert the years 1997, 1999 and 2001 for every country in the dataset?

Comment: @MateoTilburg I am not sure I understand the concern. The code with `complete` is exactly the same independent of number of countries (it is the same with 2 or 200 countries). The data.frame `df` above is something I created to demonstrate how this works, since the post only had an image of data. The above code will add the years 1997, 1999, and 2001 (or ensure every year between 1996 and 2002 is included). You can use the `tidyverse` libraries and the `complete` function as above, and it should work with your data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly, you can use **full_join()** from dplyr something like this :

```
dplyr::full_join(current_dataset,Original dataset, by=c("Country Name"="Country", "Time"="Time")
```

After that you can use select(column1,column2...) to select or unselect columns.